# C++ UWP Implementation

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

So I have been working on a racing game, so I would like to add steering wheel support. I'm using UWP([here is the page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/racing-wheel-and-force-feedback)). I have added the code to appxmanifest like Microsoft says you should do, but I still get error messages. Here is the code:

**Input.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Input.h"
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <windows.gaming.input.h>
#include <windows.gaming.input.custom.h>
#include <windows.gaming.input.forcefeedback.h>

Input::Input()
{

}

bool Input::Detect()
{
    Windows::Gaming::Input::RacingWheel RacingWheel;

    auto Wheels = ref new Vector<RacingWheel^>();

    for (auto racingwheel : RacingWheel::RacingWheels)
    {
        Wheels->Append(racingwheel);
    }
};
```

**Input.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <windows.gaming.input.h>
#include <windows.gaming.input.custom.h>
#include <windows.gaming.input.forcefeedback.h>

ref class Input sealed
{
public:
    Input();
    bool Detect();

private:
    void Acquire();

};
```

The errors are as follows:

```
RacingWheel::RacingWheels
```

-Name followed by :: must be a class or namespace

```
Vector<RacingWheel^>
```

-expected type identifier

-expected an expression

I'm new to C++ so any help is appreciated.

Comment: That is not C++. Is it C++/CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing C++/Cx and regular C++. If you are writing in C++ you can not use `ref` and `^` syntax and should use regular COM instead, if you are writing in C++/Cx you don't need to include UWP headers such as `#include <windows.gaming.input.h>` but need to compile as C++/Cx by creating appropriate kind of VS project.

Also you need to make sure that you are targeting Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0.14393) so Wheel is awailable.